# Stuttering video playback on ubuntu 20.04. No matter if youtube, VLC or game

Tags: 20.04, video, games, vlc, minecraft

I am kinda new to Ubuntu. I decided earlier this year to gradually switch to a Linux environment from windows, firstly because they have started to bug me a lot and secondly because I really found intriguing the freedom of the OS.

So I got this really weird issue where, video playback stutters every second or two no matter the context. Say I'm watching a YT video, it stutters or say I'm checking the menus in the OS and the animations feel choppy. I tried Minecraft and still couldn't enjoy the game.

Here is my hardware info from neofetch and Inxi as requested:

[image: screenshot of terminal showing output of neofetch]
[image: screenshot of terminal showing output of inxi -CG]

What could be the problem? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Install `inxi` & add results of `inxi -CG` to your post

Comment: Ok I edited the question with the inxi results

Comment: I am thinking the answer is just... Linux is not good for gaming... period. I dual boot with Windows 10 because I cannot get Ubuntu to play my games well... (Steam, Cities: Skylines... lover end games too!) I have a regular "hiccup" on the video rendering. I am running the proprietary drivers for Nvidia... my rig is a high-end gaming rig... So, go figure. I am consigned that Linux is for Browsing and productivity, Windows 10 for gaming. I don't know about other varieties of Linux, just Ubuntu, 20.04 I have waited since version 16.04... and the video has not gotten one ounce better.

Comment: You're using the driver version 440 and the [recommended gfx driver for RTX 2060 is 450](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/163238/en-us).Try installing and using that.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with @joeyH. as I have played number of games on Linux/Ubuntu using steam and others. You might say if a game is not supported on Ubuntu/Linux, it might not play well, but generalising 'Linux is not good for gaming' is not correct. I'm getting the stutter too when watching video and no other apps are running, and still trying to find out what could be the issue for that.